# Handling [re]moved lines with Meld visual diff and merge tool

Tags: merge, meld, mergetool, three-way-merge

I have a question about the Meld visual diff and merge tool, which is probably a simple misunderstanding.
But how do I adopt lines that were removed in the `$REMOTE`?

Please see the screenshot below for an example. I have changed the order of the imports and created a merge conflict, so now I want to pull the first change from the right, but then also the second change that would remove those lines that now already exist at top of the imports. I could remove them manually of course, but surely there is an easier way?

Or am I wrong with my assumption, that the middle pane is the result that gets written to `$MERGED`?

[image: Three-way merge screenshot]

Edit: In this contrived example, I actually have a *Delete* action that I can use to remove those lines. But in a real-world merge I'm trying to do with meld the *Delete* action is greyed out, as is the *Pull from Right* action.
Any idea why Meld wouldn't allow me to *Delete* those lines that will be made obsolete by a *Pull from Right* above them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out that holding the Shift key allows me to remove individual changes.

Comment: What a hidden feature! Thanks!

Comment: This is documented here: https://meldmerge.org/help/file-changes.html